# Delta updates to dashboard in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am looking at retrieving data from an API in Power BI.

I would like to avoid processing all of the data again when I run a refresh.  Is there a way to add the new data to the existing data in the dashboard as a delta upload instead of a full refresh every time?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy Premium for this. Power BI Premium supports Incremental refresh (see [announcement](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/incremental-refresh-in-power-bi-premium/) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-incremental-refresh)).

With Incremental refresh you define two parameters, RangeStart and RangeEnd, and policies how to refresh the deltas. The values for these parameters are managed by the service. Then first refresh will be slow, because it will load all the data, but next refreshes will only load the data for the period after the last refresh.